# Python - Problem to paint different colours in x,y and z axis with Ipyvolume library

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot, graph-visualization

I'm trying to create a 3D plot with Python library "ipyvolume" where every point in the plot has a colour. The points can be repeated colours. There is a problem when it paint the points in the plot. Some idea to fix this?

---

Import the libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipyvolume as ipv
```

Load the data:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/j/Desktop/K - Means/test.csv",sep=",")
dataframe.head()
```

Picture about Dataframe:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFo52.png)

Creation of the axes:

```
X = np.array(dataframe[["op","ex","ag"]])
y = np.array(dataframe['categoria'])
```

Information about X:

```
array([[34.297953, 41.948819, 29.370315],
       [44.986842, 37.938947, 24.279098],
       [41.733854, 38.999896, 34.645521],
       [40.377154, 52.337538, 31.082154],
       [36.664677, 48.530806, 31.138871],
       [33.531771, 43.211667, 25.786667],
       [31.851102, 47.182362, 19.594331],
       [31.865118, 55.377559, 36.258346],
       [46.393488, 39.93031 , 16.658062],
       [39.436667, 32.966288, 32.291591],
       [52.750992, 41.698855, 17.057176],
       [41.328182, 39.173333, 21.070505],
       [54.407727, 34.104318, 18.771818],
       [47.610076, 39.439545, 21.438409],
       [39.435149, 41.479403, 21.004104],
       [48.617348, 43.617955, 19.263258],
       [40.073543, 44.194724, 33.921417],
       [43.37292 , 43.792263, 21.067737],
       [49.792403, 41.435581, 16.433953],
       [30.020465, 44.29969 , 39.117984],
       [36.909459, 51.947297, 34.687568],
       [50.594462, 41.383154, 17.896538],
       [34.186667, 18.693542,  9.682292],
       [31.215455, 44.180909, 32.87    ],
       [47.27686 , 41.973372, 12.40186 ],
       [45.369773, 35.925909, 23.478258],
       [35.943438, 45.519531, 28.02125 ],
       [36.272348, 40.065152, 28.706894],
       [44.501603, 46.598931, 29.535038],
       [49.028308, 38.450462, 19.791538],
       [34.235923, 41.231615, 14.153692],
       [53.11048 , 39.00608 , 17.2064  ],
       [49.28542 , 42.117786, 21.008931],
       [52.895725, 38.620229, 19.972748],
       [30.691797, 59.824844, 33.395938],
       [34.949528, 50.177402, 36.325276],
       [41.76596 , 49.865253, 30.071414],
       [30.825938, 55.912578, 29.489922],
       [38.948976, 44.460866, 27.345827],
       [46.955854, 35.376179, 23.747561],
       [45.053969, 48.950992, 24.374427],
       [45.088504, 50.765276, 25.71252 ],
       [42.444615, 45.780231, 24.745615],
       [40.046439, 37.722197, 30.568258],
       [52.535221, 35.290973, 15.793009],
       [56.691163, 31.135698, 20.439651],
       [48.709282, 44.728513, 19.387538],
       [53.453713, 38.522321, 16.655907],
       [31.450855, 45.490983, 40.583162],
       [31.891474, 53.373368, 24.296316],
       [49.077731, 45.670798, 17.449202],
       [36.196989, 42.358817, 24.191613],
       [38.91342 , 46.979524, 28.669524],
       [60.225087, 28.902609, 14.337043],
       [35.545054, 30.295484, 39.422796],
       [56.815859, 38.419375, 13.961641],
       [49.47    , 30.96626 , 23.053053],
       [47.811742, 41.36447 , 20.816439],
       [35.779512, 31.227724, 27.689919],
       [55.974031, 33.09    , 21.330698],
       [40.502021, 34.040957, 16.767979],
       [38.78828 , 36.947204, 24.048172],
       [52.082462, 39.402308, 16.628231],
       [57.427596, 33.121827, 12.412404],
       [39.528547, 42.353077, 23.810769],
       [39.36155 , 40.205116, 26.27124 ],
       [66.665564, 26.855564, 15.602331],
       [48.587099, 26.988702,  9.948168],
       [52.675729, 35.32625 , 16.510208],
       [45.813043, 53.54587 , 30.403261],
       [44.765313, 43.954375, 24.824609],
       [42.643386, 33.345984, 14.643386],
       [44.512578, 37.723594, 15.144922],
       [51.830571, 44.304667, 10.049524],
       [42.202857, 38.628681, 21.68989 ],
       [57.241308, 33.237462, 16.194154],
       [36.353298, 39.223723, 26.603617],
       [35.566589, 48.679535, 29.923023],
       [33.422105, 56.539263, 32.230842],
       [31.7503  , 44.3443  , 39.1499  ],
       [33.332362, 46.603622, 37.348898],
       [41.929385, 41.960077, 17.815385],
       [57.145227, 31.194545, 16.385   ],
       [46.137348, 43.874697, 15.843258],
       [49.331231, 34.458231, 23.982462],
       [44.171154, 43.299846, 27.451538],
       [49.322373, 41.494915, 14.199153],
       [46.158281, 47.806719, 23.341641],
       [48.355859, 35.778281, 15.101563],
       [47.143474, 40.162316, 20.52    ],
       [48.403333, 36.152326, 12.157829],
       [40.281616, 35.341515, 20.805657],
       [49.049323, 32.918647, 22.447594],
       [47.737462, 41.528077, 19.694385],
       [48.743333, 42.93187 , 17.984797],
       [38.766702, 42.88383 , 22.15266 ],
       [38.471406, 41.289922, 39.664375],
       [54.911368, 42.269895, 11.263263],
       [37.240989, 46.254286, 31.804286],
       [46.319462, 38.176692, 14.143846],
       [53.331333, 33.349333, 18.497333],
       [51.006406, 36.351563, 22.484609],
       [47.646364, 39.943939, 23.249848],
       [32.683125, 54.681667, 35.906667],
       [65.067447, 25.46617 , 14.787447],
       [54.431756, 37.019847, 19.690305],
       [35.834375, 44.595625, 23.930625],
       [39.546441, 45.188475, 25.213644],
       [41.114   , 41.884769, 19.713231],
       [50.898163, 38.136837, 19.937347],
       [45.669015, 44.523106, 20.548864],
       [37.411719, 43.379531, 33.332422],
       [31.541828, 47.688172, 28.897527],
       [41.483701, 50.352283, 30.561496],
       [36.813721, 52.722403, 14.703256],
       [43.81828 , 42.931613, 17.494624],
       [39.31561 , 30.73935 , 13.23122 ],
       [63.995606, 26.921818,  9.305985],
       [44.541328, 45.529453, 33.89125 ],
       [35.420439, 41.05807 , 24.249737],
       [45.162043, 34.678602, 22.719355],
       [38.499688, 46.513828, 34.344766],
       [55.293566, 49.822326, 20.592791],
       [46.21    , 35.002222, 19.006667],
       [54.151721, 32.722131, 11.041475],
       [43.443893, 23.982901, 17.032443],
       [40.120985, 27.149545, 23.975758],
       [53.95    , 42.411488, 16.108347],
       [48.796045, 46.014478, 14.642985],
       [43.805615, 36.315846, 21.608308],
       [51.161   , 44.074   , 17.386154],
       [58.380294, 45.653922, 12.822843],
       [40.345769, 37.003923, 17.285538],
       [40.808939, 43.961591, 18.982424],
       [57.962308, 33.373538, 17.684   ],
       [35.569389, 38.904885, 31.624351],
       [31.960417, 48.533125, 40.096458],
       [71.696129, 27.57121 , 19.093548],
       [51.537405, 36.465344, 23.008168],
       [36.258913, 45.225652, 39.427283]])
```

Information about y:

```
array([7, 7, 4, 2, 4, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 3, 1, 1, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 3,
       3, 7, 2, 4, 8, 1, 4, 3, 8, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 2, 6, 1,
       1, 2, 6, 3, 1, 7, 2, 8, 6, 2, 8, 2, 1, 3, 8, 2, 8, 4, 2, 1, 8, 9,
       1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 4, 9, 2, 8, 4, 4, 9, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2, 7, 2, 3,
       2, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2, 1, 7, 7, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 8, 7, 5,
       9, 9, 8, 9, 7, 1, 8, 2, 4, 8, 8, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1,
       1, 7, 3, 7, 4, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

In this piece of code I am trying to add different colours by every point in the plot:

```
fig = ipv.figure()
colores=['blue','red','green','cyan','yellow','orange','black','pink','brown','purple']
asignar=[]
for row in y:
    asignar.append(colores[row])
scatter=ipv.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2],marker="sphere", color=asignar, size=2)
ipv.selector_default
ipv.show()
```

**The result of the last piece of code is an infinite execution.**

Changing the scatter's color the plot is created:

```
fig = ipv.figure()
colores=['blue','red','green','cyan','yellow','orange','black','pink','brown','purple']
asignar=[]
for row in y:
    asignar.append(colores[row])
scatter=ipv.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2],marker="sphere", color="red", size=2)
ipv.selector_default
ipv.show()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUHAx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion from https://github.com/maartenbreddels/ipyvolume/issues/12#issuecomment-284685146 might work, something like:

```
import ipyvolume as ipv
import matplotlib
c = matplotlib.cm.afmhot(np.linspace(0, 1, len(y)))
ipv.quickscatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2],marker="sphere",color=c,size=2)
```